# Tokaido: Crossroads - How are the extra points calculated for Legendary Items?

Tags: tokaido, tokaido-crossroads

The Legendary Item cards from the Crossroads expansion of Tokaido are labelled with points along the right upper corner (i.e. 1/3/5/7).

[image: Legendary Item cards]

I've read the [instructions](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/65/84/b2-tokaido-crossroads-rulebook.pdf) numerous times, but there's nothing in the section for Legendary Items that explains what these points are and how they are scored.

- Do you get extra points for each Legendary Item the same way you get extra points for Souvenirs?
- Do Legendary Items count as another family for the purposes of scoring Souvenirs. (Does that mean Buppatsu and Ema count as two families)?
- Is there some other explanation for what the points mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the process of preparing my question, I came across a clue: [the instructions I found online](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/65/84/b2-tokaido-crossroads-rulebook.pdf) depict the cards differently than the cards I have in my copy of the game. Specifically, the online PDF only shows the list of numerical values for Buppatsu and Ema. This suggests that the points listed on my cards are a misprint; the Legendary Items do not score any points beyond those described in the instructions.